# Run time error while using Ng2-charts in Angular/Node.js application

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, ng2-charts

In my Angular4 - Node.js application I am getting the following error at run time.

Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'. ("iv>

][data]="doughnutChartData" [labels]="doughnutChartLabels" [chartType]="doughnutChartType" (chartHover"): ng:///AppModule/DashboardComponent.html

The component's module.ts file looks like this :

```
import { NgModule } from '';
import { CommonModule } from '';
import { ChartsModule as Ng2Charts } from 'ng2-charts';
import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import {
         TimelineComponent,
         NotificationComponent,
         ChatComponent
        } from './components';
import { StatModule } from '../shared';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    Ng2Charts,
    DashboardRoutingModule,
    StatModule,
 ],
declarations: [
  DashboardComponent,
  TimelineComponent,
  NotificationComponent,
  ChatComponent
]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

The componenet.html file looks like this :

```
<div class="col col-sm-6">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="border: none">
        <div class="card-header claim-header-style" style="background: #FC0!important;color: #fff;">
           SUSPECT REASON
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
            <canvas baseChart height="180px" [data]="doughnutChartData" [labels]="doughnutChartLabels" [chartType]="doughnutChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="col col-sm-6">
    <div class="card mb-3" style="border:none;">
        <div class="card-header claim-header-style" style="background: #28426b!important;color: #fff;">
          REJECT REASON
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
            <canvas baseChart height="180px" [data]="doughnutChartData" [labels]="doughnutChartLabels" [chartType]="doughnutChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
            </canvas>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

What could be wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to `import 'chart.js'` inside your component where you actually using `canvas` and do not reference `chart.js` in `index. html` `<script>` section if you doing so.

Also try to import `ChartsModule` in to your `DashboardModule`

```
imports: [
   ChartsModule
]
```

as for some reason you are not doing so.

Also checkout that [issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/553)